# MVC Dynamically pass Model to partialview from a view on DropDownList change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, html.dropdownlistfor

It's a bit of a mouthful, but I have two dropdown lists in my view:

```
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.APlayerID)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.APlayerID, Model.AbzPlayers, "Please select", new { id = "abz" })
</div>  

<div>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.EPlayerID)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EPlayerID, Model.EdzPlayers, "Please select", new { id = "edz" })
</div>
```

Under these I have a partial view:

```
<div id="partialview" class="panel-body">
@Html.Partial("SingleResultsView", Model.SingleResults)
</div>
```

I want to update this partial view depending on what players have been selected from the dropdown, preferably on change.

I have looked up loads of examples on this, but can't seem to find anything that passes the filtered Model.SingleResults.Where(x=>x.abzID == abz && x.edz == edz) through. My view is in a shared folder, so it doesn't have a controller, this is always a problem when finding solutions as everyone seems to give the controller/view url!

I was able to display the partialview using something like this, but it's obviously not doing anything with abz and edz (the values from the dropdown) as i'm not sure how to pass the model:

```
$(function () {

    $('#abz').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();


        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("Shared/SingleResultsView")",
            type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (value) {
            $("#partialview").html(value);
        }
    });     
    });
});
```

Help would be HUGELY appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need an *action* that returns the partial view. A partial view can't do anything on its own.

```
public ActionResult SingleResults(string abzID, string edz)
{
    // do something with the passed params
    return PartialView("SingleResultsView", model) // where model is an instance of what the view needs to render itself with
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you don't want to try and load a partial view directly. Why? Well, that's not how the MVC pipeline works. Period. Instead, add an action method to your controller that generates the first page (the one that has the dropdown) and have the controller format and return the partial view to your javascript. Let's assume you have a controller as follows:

```
public class Players : IController
{
    //This is the method that loads the first page
    public ActionMethod Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //This method loads the partial html on change
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionMethod GetPartialView(int? abz)
    {
        var item =  items.SingleResults.Where(x=>x.abzID == abz && x.edz == edz)
        return View("partialViewName", item);
    }
}
```

The above controller uses POST (I Prefer that, but you can use GET as well) to submit a request to your controller to get the html. Then, you construct your javascript like so (assuming jQuery, right?):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#abz').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "Players/GetPartialView",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { abz: $(this).val() }
            cache: false,
            success: function (value) {
                $("#partialview").html(value);
            }
        });     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use a controller action for this. No matter where your view is located, you can call a controller action for a partial view result like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("yourAction", "yourController", new { someinput = someValue})",
        type: 'GET', //could also be post
    cache: false,
    success: function (value) {
        $("#partialview").html(value);
    });
```

your contoller action would look like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(<yourType> someInput){
...  //Do something with input
return PartialView("Shared/SingleResultsView", <your model that SingleResultsView takes>)
```

}

You can also use `onchange` attribute for the `DropDownFor` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.APlayerID, Model.AbzPlayers, "Please select", new { id = "abz", onchange = "javascript: someFunction();" });
```